# Exchange OWA stopped working after installing Tomcat

Tags: asp.net, tomcat, iis-6, exchange-server

I have a window 2003 server running exchange 2003 on IIS 6. Everything worked until I installed Tomcat/Railo on the server.

After the Tomcat install I am unable to reach the exchange server on the OWA. I understand that Tomcat is processing the servlets for railo but I am not sure how it is effecting OWA and how to fix it.

Since this has been running so long I am not sure where the files are to reinstall OWA are.

When I hit the exchange OWA site it does ask me to login but then IIS give me a 404 error

I obviously need to get this up and running since every in the company uses the OWA help!

**Added info:**

I have added a new virtual directory to the default website that contains an image.  I can hit this with no problem so it appears that what is no longer working are the virutal directories originally added by the install.

```
/exchadmin  \\.\backofficeStorage
/exchange   \\.\backofficeStaorage
/exchweb    C:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\ExchWeb
etc
```

These also appear to be ASP.NET related pages.  Is it possible that installing railo/Tomcat messed up the asp processing for this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gavin Totall put me on the right track for this.  What ever happened during the Tomcat install hosed all of the application pool settings for the default site  I found this page

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=883380

on how to reset all the default OWA virtual directorys and everything started working again.  Hopefully this post will save someone the hours I spent on this.  Thanks again @Gavin

Comment: Great news, glad you got is sorted.

Comment: You may want to take a copy of the .config files here: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that both IIS and Tomcat are trying to listen on Port 80, only one can bind at a time. If you look in IIS you may find your default website is stopped.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Tomcat is listening on :8080 and When I look at the default website (which does run OWA) it is running. I can stop amd restart it as normal.

Comment: Sorry you are right obviously as you could reach the log in form. It is curious that you get a 404 for the next page. I would examine the properties of that application in iis, and maybe try to reach a plain html file in the same location. If it is on a different sub domain maybe tomcat changed your host file?

Comment: Could it be that the tomcat installation changed the .net framework support for your application pool?

Comment: I would guess that is a good possibility but I don't know how to test or fix that.

Comment: 1.Click on one of exchange applications
2. review the basic settings of the applications - in the action panel - to get the name of the pool that the application is running under
3. Now you can look at the list of application pools and ensure that the pool that you identified is running .net

Comment: They are all running but if I try to put an image in a directory I still get a 404 for example i have a log in the exchweb dir but if I go to mydomain.com/ExchWeb/logo.gif I get a 404. Since this is not a "regular" virtual directory I am a bit afraid to change anything since I am not familiar enough to put everything back

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41817/discussion-between-gavin-and-lance)